# Converting code to read files in windows to linux

Tags: python, linux, windows, io

I'm currently getting an error from cv2 resize which is indicating that there is nothing in the file. It works fine on windows but I'm struggling to work out what needs to be done (apart from a change in the path name) for it to work on linux.

```
path1 ='C:/Users/L/Software/Data/channels/ch3'

listing = os.listdir(path1)

ch3_matrix = array([array(cv2.resize(cv2.imread(path1 + '\\' + im2,0),(55,55))).flatten()
            for im2 in listing])
```

Comment: How about changing the value of `path1` variable to the path of `ch3` on your Linux machine?

Comment: Whoops, sorry I was supposed to post that I had already updated the variable name. My bad

Comment: So what makes you think you need to change anything else?

Comment: I believe the final path you're creating isn't supposed to have a backslash but a normal slash in it. I recommend using pathlib or os.path.join generally instead of building paths with string concatenation.

Comment: Bingo, that's it. Thank you!

Comment: No problem. I wrote a short answer based on my comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the final path you're building:

```
path1 + '\\' + im2
```

where `path1` is your base directory and `im2` the image filename. Doing it like this (with string concatenation) can lead to problems very fast and is generally discouraged.

I would recommend using [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) or the newer [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) module for this, which both work platform-independent:

```
import os

BASE_PATH = 'C:/Users/L/Software/Data/channels/ch3'

images = os.listdir(BASE_PATH)
ch3_matrix = array([
    array(cv2.resize(cv2.imread(os.path.join(BASE_PATH, image), 0), (55, 55))).flatten()
    for image in images
])
```

or

```
import pathlib

BASE_PATH = pathlib.Path('C:/Users/L/Software/Data/channels/ch3')

images = os.listdir(BASE_PATH)
ch3_matrix = array([
    array(cv2.resize(cv2.imread(str(BASE_PATH / image), 0), (55, 55))).flatten()
    for image in images
])
```

For your code to work on Linux you will only have to change the `BASE_PATH`.